# Kubernetes HA Setup with External Nginx Loadbalancer or F5 Loadbalancer User "system:anonymous" cannot create nodes at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes

I am using external nginx loadbalancer and trying to configure K8s Master but its failing with below error :

> error uploading configuration: unable to create configmap: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"**

For me it more looks like cert issue but i am having hard time to find what i am missing , any help is appreciated in our infrastructure we use F5 loadbalancer in front of apiserver and i am seeing the same issue there this is the env i have created for troubleshooting

**kubeadm-config:**

```
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2
    kind: MasterConfiguration
    kubernetesVersion: v1.11.0
    apiServerCertSANs:
    - "ec2-23-23-244-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    api:
    controlPlaneEndpoint: "ec2-23-23-244-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6443"
    etcd:
    external:
        endpoints:
        - https://172.31.32.160:2379
        caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
        certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
        keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
     networking:
     # This CIDR is a calico default. Substitute or remove for your CNI provider.
     podSubnet: "10.244.0.0/16"
```

**Env :**
        Kubelet : 1.11.1 kubeadm 1.11.1 kubectl 1.11.1

**Output**

```
    [certificates] Using the existing ca certificate and key.
    [certificates] Using the existing apiserver certificate and key.
    [certificates] Using the existing apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and 
    key.
    [certificates] Using the existing sa key.
    [certificates] Using the existing front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
    [certificates] Using the existing front-proxy-client certificate and key.
    [certificates] valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
     [endpoint] WARNING: port specified in api.controlPlaneEndpoint overrides 
  api.bindPort in the controlplane address
     [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
     [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
     [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller- 
  manager.conf"




     [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
     [controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to 
  "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
     [controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager 
  to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
     [controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to 
  "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
     [init] waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods 
  from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
  [init] this might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to 
  be pulled
     [apiclient] All control plane components are healthy after 41.036802 seconds


     [uploadconfig] storing the configuration used in ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" 
     in the "kube-system" Namespace
     error uploading configuration: unable to create configmap: configmaps is 
     forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create configmaps in the 
     namespace "kube-system"
```

**logs:**

```
    Unable to register node "ip-172-31-40-157" with API server: nodes is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create nodes at the cluster scope
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:464: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes "ip-172-31-40-157" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list nodes at t
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list pods at the cluster sco
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:455: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list services at the cluster
on_manager.go:243] eviction manager: failed to get get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "ip-172-31-40-157" not found
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:464: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes "ip-172-31-40-157" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list nodes at t
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list pods at the cluster sco
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:455: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list services at the cluster
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:464: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes "ip-172-31-40-157" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list nodes at t
tor.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list pods at the cluster sco
:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
```

Nginx :

```
   upstream mywebapp1 {
      server 172.31.40.157:6443;

   }
server {
    listen 6443 ssl;
    server_name ec2-23-23-244-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /opt/certificates/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /opt/certificates/server.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /opt/certificates/ca.crt;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://mywebapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Nginx Server : 172-31-44-203
Master Server : 172-31-40-157
```

**I am using Self Signed Certs and the CA to generate all the certs including the one in nginx are same**

I had same issue in our infrastructure when we use f5 loadbalancer

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes speak to the apiserver through a load balancer, and expect to use client certificate credentials to authenticate (which is typical for nodes), the load balancer must not terminate or re-encrypt TLS, or the client certificate information will be lost and the apiserver will see the request as anonymous.

Comment: Hi Jordan, Thank you so much i been troubleshooting lot on f5 but not able to make progress just want to know when you say client certificate are you talking about apiserver.crt or just the CA certificate the ca certificate we pass at the loadbalancer is a combination of root and intermediate cert and does this communication needs to happen through  only tcp at f5 loadbalancer , i have also tried with layer 4 at f5 and now it through me the error saying authorization issue ? any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Nginx configuration for load balancing master nodes:

```
stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        least_conn;
        server master01:6443;
        server master02:6433;
        server master03:6433;
    }

    server {
        listen        6443;
        proxy_pass    stream_backend;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }
}
```